# CSV line break issue

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have this CSV file that contain this following,

```
10000,hello
10000,bye
10000,good
```

And, my code below for reading CSV file, and send them to database.

```
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (table_column1, table_column2) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".$data[0]."', 
                    '".$data[1]. "'
                ) 
            ");         
        }
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")); 

}
```

With the above, the data from CSV cannot go into database because, it read the file something like this below,

```
10000 hello 10000
bye 10000
good
```

**May i know, what the is problem with this? Is there something wrong with the codes?**

However, if the format for my CSV file is like this below (A blank line in between each line),

```
10000,hello

10000,bye

10000,good
```

All the data can go into database successsfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not do it without csv reading functions?

```
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $lines = file($file); 

    foreach ($lines as $line)
    {
        $data = explode(",", $line);
        if ($data[0] != "") { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (table_column1, table_column2) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".$data[0]."', 
                    '".$data[1]. "'
                ) 
            ");         
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Erm, still the same result, data won't go into database, it read $line like this, 

10000, 1UlmK 10000, 1PBfj 10000, 1bCNa 10000, 1RQSb 10000, 1WhQA

Comment: cant you debug or something?

Comment: Tried debugging. No error. Just that, it cannot send into database because, the data are not being read properly..But thanks for your help/thoughts.

Comment: try to `print_r($data)` in loop so you know is it read properly, might be something wrong in a way you connected to DB

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. By the way, this is the output, Array ( [0] => 10000 [1] => hello 10000 [2] => bye 10000 [3] => good)..

Comment: you dont have correct new line symbol at the end of each line. Try to resave your input file for *nix or windows (whatever server you run at). Notepad++ and many other code editors have such features.

Comment: Thanks Serg! It works! Coz i was using Mac, the excel conversion to csv is very different from Windows. I compare two csv on notepad, and realised the mac csv format is quite different on notepad. So i tried to convert on Windows excel and upload to database without blank line in between. And it is able to go into database! Thanks alot for the help!